# It Automatically select last username on login screen

Tags: login, password, login-screen, username

In ubuntu 12.04 after last updates, the system auto select the last username enter in machine and only ask for password.

How i can change that? I want it ask for username and passwork like before updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following lines:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Then restart `lightdm`:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: I dont use lightdm, i use mdm.

I open /etc/mdm/mdm.conf and edit the following line:

SelectLastLogin=false

Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a default 12.04 installation^^